# Call Back Form and SMS Submit

Tags: php, forms

i have call back form written in PHP. Its working with regular emails but i want to submit that form to SMS phone number also. When i use gmail and enter **********@txt.att.net
its working . But when i submit via my email form it isnt.

```
    <?
    $to = "*********@txt.att.net";
    $send = "<center><p class='domeni'>Vasa email je uspesno poslat.<br>Hvala !</p></center><br>";
    $subject = "Subject";
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $sub = $_POST['sub'];
    $ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");

    $body = " 
    Here are the details:

    Name - $name \n 
    Phone Number - $phone \n 
    IP Address - $ip";
    $slanje=mail($to,$subject,$body);

    if($slanje) {
       print "<META http-equiv='refresh' content='1;URL=thanks.html'>";
    } else {
        echo "ERROR!";
    }

    print "<META http-equiv='refresh' content='1;URL=thanks.html'>";
    ?>
```

Thanks in foward

Comment: What specifically isn't working? Is it not sending the email, is the email malformatted? Is content not coming through?

Comment: email is ok but SMS isnt coming to phone for 3321312@txt.att.net (use phone number of client before @). That same link is working when i try to send email directly via gmail.

Comment: you missing the from address established in the extra headers: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php